# Unknown table MySQL in Join with Union query

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to union two tables which has foreign key of another table (group_message_log). But error occurring.

Error: Unknown table 'group_message_log'

```
SELECT `message_id`,group_message_log.* FROM `messages_log` AS `log_1` JOIN `group_message_log` AS `gm` ON `message_id` = gm.id WHERE `student_id`='128' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT `message_id`,group_message_log.* FROM `message_phone_log` AS `log_2` JOIN `group_message_log` AS `gm` ON gm.id = `message_id` WHERE (`phone`='XXX' OR `phone`='XXX')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using table name with alias  `group_message_log AS gm`
so you should use alias `gm` insetad of full name `group_message_log` as below

```
SELECT `message_id`,gm.* FROM `messages_log` AS `log_1` JOIN `group_message_log` AS `gm` ON `message_id` = gm.id WHERE `student_id`='128' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT `message_id`,gm.* FROM `message_phone_log` AS `log_2` JOIN `group_message_log` AS `gm` ON gm.id = `message_id` WHERE (`phone`='XXX' OR `phone`='XXX')
```